# Android Advanced Image processing

Tags: java, android, image, editing

I want to build a Image editing application. I've gone through convolution matrix for creating basic color filters but I want the app to also have advanced editing capabilities like highlight/shadow adjustment, vignette, curves adjustments etc.

Any chances that I might find some examples for the same to learn more about it. Also, any kind of helpful resources would be a great help.

P.S. If there is an existing image editing library/sdk that can get the job done, that would be great too

Comment: The [tag: processing] tag should only be used for the Processing language.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at opencv and vxl. They are libraries of computer vision functions and have open source community around them. Opencv is a big library/community. I was looking into image processing libraries for some ideas I have (permanantly stuck in pre-development due to lack of time) and I have played with them a bit on linux. I'm still very much an opencv/vxl n00b though.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV

I found vxl a bit faster to get started with.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VXL

There is support for opencv on Android: 
http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

There is not support for vxl on android as far as I can see.

Now, both of these are pretty big projects. I would say there is ALOT to learn and it will take a while. But I think it is probably well worth-while learning. There are many tutorials and examples.

Get the source code first:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv

$ git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/vxl/git vxl
```

Especially for a mobile platform it will be important to get the use of image processing right - so that it doesn't kill battery of device - so . . . lots of experimenting and testing and learning to do!

Have fun!

Comment: I looked into OpenCV and its massive. Also, I am not a pro at Java right now, so implementing this in the app in due time would be a tough challenge. I was looking for something a bit more mobile friendly and basic, for construction of filters and basic adjustments.